# What is the difference between writing a common function in AppController.php versus writing it inside a component in Cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using Cakephp 2.5.1. I have a common function which is to be shared by all controllers. I can either do it inside AppController.php or inside a Component. What is the difference? What are the pros and cons of the different methods? Under what conditions should I use which method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when we write any function to the AppController.php  the this function is available for all the Controller even if we don't need it,because all the Controllers extends the AppController.

Better to write function in component then we are able to use component in any specific Controller in which the function is required.

Its clearly mentioned in Documention :- [link to documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller)